# Bootstrap .Constructor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the Bootstrap plugin definition, I saw the following:

```
// Dropdown plugin
$.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown

// Modal plugin
$.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal

// Similarly, on other plugins as well e.g. Tooltip, etc.
```

Any reasons why they'd need that assignment, considering `Dropdown` and `Modal` are in fact constructors?

```
var Modal = function (element, options) {
  ...
}
```

Is using `.Constructor` property name a convention? I might be wrong, but `.Constructor` is an arbitrary property, right?

Answer (score 0):

It allows checking of the variable's type in JS. For example, by defining the the Constructor property, it's possible to easily assess the type as follows:

```
var myModal = new modal();
if(myModal.constructor == Modal)
{
    // do something
}
```

Since Bootstrap's JavaScript uses the same constructor for some of its JavaScript elements (Popovers require Tooltip, for example) it's likely used within the Bootstrap code to determine which type of element a variable refers to.

Comment: You're right: that particular property is for their "internal" use. For example, `Popover.prototype = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype)`. I initially was wondering whether it's a JS best practice or OO convention.